# Deploy yii2 advanced on Heroku and frontend cannot find the models

Tags: heroku, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I deployed a yii2 advanced and postgresql on the Heroku. 
The backend works well. 
When I visit frontend, it gives me an error.

```
Error

Class 'frontend\models\home' not found


public function getHomeSource()
{
    $query = Home::find();
    $home_list = $query->where('"isUsed" = 1')->orderBy('sort')->all();

    return $home_list;
}
```

I don't know how to fix it.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you give all content of file with function `getHomeSource()` 
Mabe you need just add `use name\spase\tohomemodel\Home` in top of the file